# No me funciona la etiqueta "function" en VSCode

Tags: javascript, funciones

Intento aplicar funciones de JavaScript en mi código HTML con la etiqueta script y los cambios no se ven reflejados en el browser. Por ejemplo:

```
`$("#ejemplo h2, #ejemplo button, #ejemplo fieldset").mouseover(function () {
    console.log("Pasaste con el raton por sobre los elementos");
});  `
```

(Probé si funcionaba en Sublime pero tampoco)

Comment: Coloca tu código completo. HTML + JS. Lo más probable es que sea un error tuyo y no de ningún editor de texto.

Comment: Por lo que se ve es código JS pero usando jQuery, correcto?

Comment: Sí, estoy usando JQuery. Sigo sin darme cuenta qué estoy haciendo mal.

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que has importado la librería de jQuery con una etiqueta de script previo a ejecutar dicho selector.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```js
$("#ejemplo h2, #ejemplo button, #ejemplo fieldset").mouseover(function () {
    console.log("Pasaste con el raton por sobre los elementos");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="ejemplo">
  <h2>
    Test
  </h2>
  
  <button>
   Test2
  </button>
  
  <fieldset>
   Test3
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

En este caso se puede comprobar que funcionaría correctamente.